# adding a transition when an image changes on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

i working on a react project and i made a card with an image that changes when you hover over it and i would like to add a transition when the image changes to make it smother, itried using
`transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;` but it not working.

here is my code can someone help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKM6U.gif)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './Article.css';

// import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

function Article(props) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className='article'
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
    >
      <img
        className='article__image'
        src={isHovered ? props.hoverImage : props.image}
        alt={props.title}
      />
      <h3 className='article__title'>{props.title}</h3>
      <p className='article__price'>{props.price}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Article;
```

```
.article{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


.article__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  object-fit:cover;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

i tried using transition property `transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;`
i would like the first image to fade away and reveal the second image on something that make the transition somther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should change `probs` to `props`.

Change in img `src` prop cannot be animated in CSS, but you can use a small trick to achive what you want.

Instead of your img element use:

```
<div className="article__image">
  <img
    data-visible={isHovered}
    className="article__image absolute"
    src={props.hoverImage}
    alt={props.title}
  />
  <img
    data-visible={!isHovered}
    className="article__image"
    src={props.image}
    alt={props.title}
  />
</div>
```

So, I made 2 img elements and gave them a `data-visible` prop with opposite values. I've also added `position: absolute;` to the first one so they stay on each other. Then you need to add this to your CSS file.

```css
.article__image[data-visible="false"] {
  opacity: 0;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

The first class does the trick - it hides elements with the `article__image` class when their `data-visible` prop is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue with your code, you have a typo in the class name. You have added the className as `articale` in your JSX but in CSS you have named as `article`.

I think this might work.